# How can I pass method's names from data in script section to @click on Vue

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Hello i am new on vuetify i am trying to use data like this the action is the method name:

```
data: () => ({
    profile: [
      { title: 'Profile', action: 'userProfile' },
      { title: 'Settings', action: 'UserSettings' },
      { divider: true },
      { title: 'Log out', action: 'userLogout' }
    ]
  }),
```

In

```
<app-bar-item v-else :key="item-${index}" to="/">
        <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title" @click="userLogout" />
        </v-list-item-content>
</app-bar-item>
```

specifically in

```
@click="userLogout"
```

some like @CLick="item.action" obtained from data in script section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@click is expecting a method and not data. What you can do is, add a middleman function and pass `item.action` to the middleman. The middleman will then call the expected method.

```
<v-list-item-title v-text="item.title" @click="middleman(item.action)" />

...
methods: {
  middleman(action){
    switch(action){
      case 'userProfile':
         //Go to user profile
      break;
      case 'UserSettings':
         // Go to user settings
      break;
      case 'userLogout':
         // Logout the user
      break;
    }

  }
}
```